# Infinte constructor loop

Tags: c++, oop

The design problem is that the constructor of one type creates an object of another type whose constructor again creates a object of the first type.

Definitions:

```
class A
{
  A();
  B* b;
}
class B
{
  B();
  A* a;
}
```

Implementation:

```
A::A()
{
  b = new B(); 
}

B::B()
{
  a = new A();
}
```

What would a solution be to this?

Comment: What's the question? You should avoid this infinite loop.

Comment: Oh nice, and what is your question?

Comment: Looks like a XY-problem to me. What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @RSahu That is not the problem.

Comment: @J.Doe If an `A` needs to own a distinct `B` and a `B` needs to own a distinct `A` there is no solution. You need an infinite number of `A`s and `B`s. You need to rethink the design that leads to this impossible requirement.

Comment: @J.Doe _"What would a solution be to this?"_ If `B` needs a reference to `A` to work with, you should pass `A` to `B`'s constructor as a reference (pointer) parameter.

Comment: "What would a solution be to this?" - How about "Don't do that" ?

Comment: Thanks I have already found a solution to this.

Comment: Consider using Two Phase construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The design problem is that the constructor of one type creates an object of another type whose constructor again creates a object of the first type.

Solution to infinite recursion is to not do it.

Either have no (mutual) recursion at all, or terminate the recursion at some point. For example, you could change the design of the classes so that `A` creates a `B`, but `B` doesn't create an `A`.

Comment: @RSahu then the solution is to get rid of the requirement ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to model something infinite (in which case this is the wrong approach), there should be a finite number of elements in your data structure.

Even if `A` needs a `B` and `B` needs an `A`, does *every* `A` need a `B` and does *every* `B` need a `A`?

- No: Then add a condition (which likely will require adding a constructor argument) that breaks the chain and sets its member to `nullptr`.
- Yes: Does every `A` needs a *new* `B` or could it use an existing one instead (and similarly for the other direction)?

  - Can use existing: Pass along an existing `A` or `B` as needed to break the chain.
  - Must be new: You're modeling something infinite.  Generate data lazily instead.